# Mysql 5.6 (Percona): How to Improve Query Performance of UPDATE and INSERT?

Tags: mysql, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster

I'm running a Percona 5.6 cluster (3 nodes) on lxc containers. Each nodes hardware is as follows:

```
4 x Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz (2 Sockets)
16GB RAM
130GB HD
```

My database is just under 4GB in size. I've managed to tweak the config settings so selects are handled swiftly. However, I'm seeing some UPDATE and INSERT performing quite slow (5 seconds+). So there must be some sort of bottleneck which i'm wondering if I can resolve via config tweaking.

I'm aware that a couple of the tables may require some unused indexes to be dropped, but I was wondering what else to look into to improve the performance of the queries. Load isn't really that big, it's about 100 users as it's an internal system.

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size: 8G
innodb_log_file_size: 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size: 128M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit: 2
innodb_thread_concurrency: 0
innodb_flush_method: O_DIRECT
innodb_file_per_table: ON
```

Here is my SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS:

```
| InnoDB |      | 
=====================================
2018-08-14 15:22:02 7f3330863700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 9 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 22626 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 79338 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 101963
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 86267
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 1537634
Mutex spin waits 800672, rounds 1115180, OS waits 19238
RW-shared spins 605666, rounds 2660513, OS waits 58073
RW-excl spins 79517, rounds 2104544, OS waits 8150
Spin rounds per wait: 1.39 mutex, 4.39 RW-shared, 26.47 RW-excl
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 1057692300
Purge done for trx's n:o < 1057692300 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 2030
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 621427, OS thread handle 0x7f3330863700, query id 7014924 localhost myuser init
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
---TRANSACTION 0, not started
MySQL thread id 608823, OS thread handle 0x7f33311c8700, query id 6968932 10.0.10.200 myuser
---TRANSACTION 1057692298, not started
MySQL thread id 2, OS thread handle 0x7f35905c8700, query id 7014913 committed 7569847
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: 0 [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads: 0, log i/o's: 0, sync i/o's: 0
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
189853 OS file reads, 666579 OS file writes, 119023 OS fsyncs
0.00 reads/s, 0 avg bytes/read, 14.78 writes/s, 2.89 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 926, seg size 928, 3164 merges
merged operations:
 insert 3331, delete mark 1275, delete 655
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
9.67 hash searches/s, 95.66 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 75281381079
Log flushed up to   75281381079
Pages flushed up to 75281381079
Last checkpoint at  75281381079
Max checkpoint age    434154333
Checkpoint age target 420587011
Modified age          0
Checkpoint age        0
0 pending log writes, 0 pending chkp writes
142005 log i/o's done, 2.00 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total memory allocated 8942256128; in additional pool allocated 0
Total memory allocated by read views 776
Internal hash tables (constant factor + variable factor)
    Adaptive hash index 411468128   (151384312 + 260083816)
    Page hash           1107208 (buffer pool 0 only)
    Dictionary cache    39612436    (35402768 + 4209668)
    File system         1602712     (812272 + 790440)
    Lock system         21251648    (21250568 + 1080)
    Recovery system     0   (0 + 0)
Dictionary memory allocated 4209668
Buffer pool size        524280
Buffer pool size, bytes 8589803520
Free buffers            82805
Database pages          425581
Old database pages      157253
Modified db pages       0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 223, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 189492, created 236089, written 496948
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 12.55 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 425581, unzip_LRU len: 38
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
----------------------
INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
----------------------
---BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size        65535
Buffer pool size, bytes 1073725440
Free buffers            9846
Database pages          53705
Old database pages      19844
Modified db pages       0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 27, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 24150, created 29555, written 83723
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 3.56 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 53705, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size        65535
Buffer pool size, bytes 1073725440
Free buffers            9114
Database pages          54443
Old database pages      20117
Modified db pages       0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 28, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 24455, created 29988, written 46033
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.67 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 54443, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 2
Buffer pool size        65535
Buffer pool size, bytes 1073725440
Free buffers            10545
Database pages          53012
Old database pages      19588
Modified db pages       0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 27, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 23505, created 29507, written 64763
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 1.89 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 53012, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 3
Buffer pool size        65535
Buffer pool size, bytes 1073725440
Free buffers            9551
Database pages          53984
Old database pages      19947
Modified db pages       0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 16, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 24437, created 29547, written 61138
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.89 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 53984, unzip_LRU len: 5
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 4
Buffer pool size        65535
Buffer pool size, bytes 1073725440
Free buffers            10559
Database pages          52987
Old database pages      19579
Modified db pages       0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 29, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 23524, created 29463, written 69996
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 2.11 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 52987, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 5
Buffer pool size        65535
Buffer pool size, bytes 1073725440
Free buffers            10906
Database pages          52633
Old database pages      19448
Modified db pages       0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 33, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 23070, created 29563, written 60299
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 1.56 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 52633, unzip_LRU len: 33
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 6
Buffer pool size        65535
Buffer pool size, bytes 1073725440
Free buffers            10544
Database pages          53001
Old database pages      19583
Modified db pages       0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 20, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 23685, created 29316, written 52866
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.78 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 53001, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 7
Buffer pool size        65535
Buffer pool size, bytes 1073725440
Free buffers            11740
Database pages          51816
Old database pages      19147
Modified db pages       0
Pending reads 0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 43, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 22666, created 29150, written 58130
0.00 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 1.11 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 51816, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
0 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
0 read views open inside InnoDB
0 RW transactions active inside InnoDB
0 RO transactions active inside InnoDB
0 out of 1000 descriptors used
Main thread process no. 74272, id 139857921410816, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 12277268, updated 41111, deleted 326, read 31539377489
0.11 inserts/s, 0.67 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 27069.99 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
```

**UPDATE 1**

Here are some details about the table which has the problem most often:

```
Engine: Innodb
Row format: Compact
Column Count: 124
Table Row: 581705 (I know, not alot!)
AVG row length: 560
Data lenght: 310.9MB
Index lenght: 411.4MB
Max data length: 0.0bytes
Data free: 4.0mb
Table size (estimate): 722.3MB
file format: antelope
Auto Increment: 745745
Table collation: utf8_unicode_ci

Number of Indices: 34 (most are BTREE, single column, non-unique Indices)
```

I think my biggest problem with this table is 1) the number of indecies and 2) the data types used. There is quite alot of usage of 'bigint(20) unsigned' which I can't only imagine to be totally unnecessary. Along with 'mediumtext' fields too.

I suspect the inserts are slow due to the updates being slow. And I suspect that is do to the number of indexes and the large data types used.

However, I've got plenty of available CPU/Ram that I can throw at it if needed and would like to know if there is any further configurations I might want to look at.

**UPDATE 2**

I've enabled userstat to determine some unused indexes since the last time mysql was restarted (https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/06/30/find-unused-indexes/). It turns out that i've only used 15 out of 34 indexes.

**UPDATE 3**

Here is a status output during a thread backup:

https://pastebin.com/QhkHGH5s

Comment: 0.11 inserts/s, 0.67 updates/s, 0.00 deletes/s, 27069.99 reads/s.   Was this taken when Updates are slow?  I assume performance stinks across all 3 containers?  What type of disk backs the containers? Connected locally, NFS, iSCSI, FibreChannel?  Can you get into the container and run `iostat -xm 5` to see disk performance stats?  If you can, spin up a new container with benchmarking tools and figure out if it's MySQL, or the underlying infrastructure that needs help.   Does Percona offer performance review as part of support?

Comment: @KevinBott All the containers are connected to local data directories via a ceph raid array, which I believe is ZFS. The status was requested when things are normal. I'll try to catch one when a slow down occurs.

Comment: Thanks for asking. Percona has an open source software forum for those using our free software - all of our software is open source and free, and it is free to post tech questions to our forum (free apart from an email address). https://www.percona.com/forums/ We offer paid support, managed services and consultancy. This probably doesn't help the op right now, as the majority of users work with our os software without contracting our services. However, I will ask someone from the Percona XtraDB Cluster team if they can see any obvious issues in this scenario.

Comment: @David are you able to provide information about the under-performing write queries themselves along with table structure for each associated table? Also, are you writing to one node or all of them?

Comment: @Cez I've updated my questions with some details about the main culprit (table). Query wise, nearly all update commands are slow. And when you get more then one occurring, a backup starts to happen.

Comment: I would also enable the slow-query log, with `log_slow_verbosity=full` so you can see InnoDB stats per query as well as lock time. You would like to know where the time is being spent during your updates. Is it waiting on locks? Is it waiting for IO? See https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/LATEST/diagnostics/slow_extended.html

Comment: @KevinBott I've posted a pastbin of a innodb status during a thread backup. I'm currently trying to see if anything sheds light on what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all if you are not monitoring already, not collecting the same data, or just like the look of it you may benefit from using [PMM](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-and-management/index.html) to get a better insight in real-time. You can compare the servers and look for potential issues, such as saturating I/O, commit pile-ups, etc. There's a [live demo version](https://pmmdemo.percona.com/) that will give you the idea.

There isn't so much to go on without a table structure and example queries, which would help rule out the queries themselves rather than something else, but here are a few observations:

- presuming that the stats are up-to-date, you have more data in indexes that data alone, which could be a sign that you need to clean-up indexes and are having to do more work updating indexes than necessary
- the table that was posted shows the older `Antelope` format being used, which was superseded by the `Barracuda` format; you mention `mediumtext` fields and it is usually most efficient to store all of the value off-page, which the [dynamic row format of Barracuda](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-row-format-dynamic.html) allows
- you have `innodb_adaptive_hash_index` enabled, but this might not be [beneficial for your workload](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/04/12/is-adaptive-hash-index-in-innodb-right-for-my-workload/), as your misses look to be much higher than hits, yet maintenance of the AHI would still be required

It is also unclear as to whether you are sending writes to a single node, or spreading them. Galera doesn't help you scale your writes, so if you are writing to multiple nodes and are seeing [conflicts](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages/dealingwithmultimasterconflicts.html) then maybe switching to using a single node may assist.